# Web Page to Windows phone app communication

Tags: javascript, windows-phone

I have a windows phone 8  app that opens up a webpage inside the Web browser Control. The webpage has a button that when pressed needs to inform the app that 'I've been pressed', so that the app can perform some task. Is there a way to perform such task on windows phone? I found a couple of articles where IPhone native app did a similar thing 
[Any way for webview to communicate with native iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046865/any-way-for-webview-to-communicate-with-native-ios-app)
But found no luck for windows phone.