# is it possible to trigger a function from a html page to an iphone app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am creating an iphone app right now and there is a `UIWebView` in one of the pages. the page that gets loaded has a link, I was wondering if there is anyway to trigger a function inside the app when the link is clicked. Technically I just want to create a back button if the link was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` in your view controller and get notified when the webview is about to load another webpage.

Example:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
   // Check here if the link was clicked by checking the request object

   return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to call `[webView setDelegate:self`] in your `viewDidLoad` method (or directly hook it up in IB)

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi Added an example

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742635/474535

Another article about UIWebview communication TO objective C

http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/10/18/uiwebview-communication-to-objective-c/

Comment: It looks like he wants it the other way around?

Comment: yea @JustSid is right, I want it the other way around, I want the webpage to send the request to the app

Comment: @JustSid: I read he wants something from webview to objective c (the app) that's what the article says. Note that I updated the link. The article is about sending a string from webview to app

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URL schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18) if its your own webpage