# WebKit in an OSX App: Passing messages from Javascript to the wrapper application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webkit

In reading the WebKit documentation, I see I can [directly evaluate Javascript in the embedded browser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001214-BCIIEAFH). Great! This handles passing messages from the native OSX app into the website.

However, I also need to be able to pass messages from my Javascript to trigger some code in the OSX application. I know how I would do this on the ***iPhone UIWebView***: I would implement the UIWebViewDelegate class, and then implement a method like this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
     // Examine the request object and do whatever needs be done
     return NO;
}
```

Coincidentally, I see that [other users have come up with this solution for the iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742590/nsstring-in-webview-iphone-and-objective-c/3742635#3742635). However, I see no equivalent method in the OSX WebKit framework (eg, within the [Frame Load Delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/LocationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002027-CJBEHAAG)).

Can anyone suggest best practices for passing a message from my Javascript to my OSX app?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I didn't dig deep enough before asking.
In WebKit, you can directly call Objective-C methods from Javascript by exposing the Objective-C class. Check out this documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html

Very easy to use, and super useful.

*EDIT*
For the sake of completeness:
If you're looking for a way to intercept (and even block) page load calls (like I did in the UIWebView example above), check out the [documentation for the WebKit policyDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/PolicyDecisions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001496-CJBEHAAG). You can choose to ignore (or use) events of a certain type.