# Imitating keyboard delete key with a button

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uikeyboard

I am using a `UIWebView` for text and emoticon/smiley display in my app. I can input and delete the text and emoticons using the keyboard, but I want to have a button in the UI which will do the same thing. How can I imitate the keyboard delete functionality with my own button?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you have to set up some sort of communication between the native app and the webview so that you can pass certain events to be handled accordingly. Check out the post here [NSString in UIWebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742590/nsstring-in-webview-iphone-and-objective-c/3742635#3742635) that might shed some light on how you can solve your problem.