# Event on html alert in xcode

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, xcode, events

I have an HTML file that calculates various cable sizes with my xcode project (all the rest is in objective c), if a cable is out of range it fires an alert `alert ("No suitable cables");` upon this I would like to trigger an action.  Can I tell my app that the event has happened when its in HTML? Ive heard  of  listners and think I may need to use in this circumstance maybe? Not sure how I would implement it thought

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742590/nsstring-in-webview-iphone-and-objective-c/3742635#3742635

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by in the webview triggering a URL that would load a custom prefix that you can look for in the webview's `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method in the javascript if a cable alert needs to be sent.

`ex. sendCableAlert://scenario1.com`

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *alertPrefix = @"sendCableAlert://";

    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:alertPrefix]) {
        //You've hit an alert do something..
        NSLog(@"CABLE ALERT!");

        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think Im understanding the second part of the code and the principals behind this,  but I still dont fully understand.  The `sendCableAlert://scenario1.com`, does that go in my html file?

Comment: Yes you would have the javascript trigger that in something like a loadUrl(http://somesite.com) which i'm guessing will be conditionally sent based on the outcome of your calculations.

Comment: I think thats where im confused, the load url? I dont have that im my html code, its a calculator in a local html file (sorry should have stated that) ` ...` form.percentage_drop.value = Math.round(mycable.percentage_drop(I,l,V) * 10 )/10;
      form.current.value = Math.round(I*100)/100;
     } else {
      alert("No suitable cables");
     }
    }

Comment: try this then  form.percentage_drop.value = Math.round(mycable.percentage_drop(I,l,V) * 10 )/10; form.current.value = Math.round(I*100)/100; } else { loadURL(sendCableAlert://testingprefix); } }  // I just got the js from quickly googling loadURL javascript.

Comment: That way where you are doing your js alert now, its simply using javascript to try to load a URL, which obj-c will see as not really a URL but just a way to pass a message back to the viewcontroller

Comment: Tried and tried with this but im just not getting it, thanks for your time.  Will have to think of a workaround